# Getting java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError while using Google Gson library

Tags: eclipse, classpath, gson, apache-httpclient-4.x, apache-httpcomponents

I am using `Gson library` to convert objects to `Json` and vice versa. I have copied the `jars` of that library into a new folder `lib` and added it to the build path for the project in my `Eclipse IDE`.

I have one main class where I convert an object into Json using `toJson()` shown below and send it to a `servlet` using `Apache HttpClient's HttpPost()`.

```
Gson gson= new Gson();
String json = gson.toJson(names);
```

But in the `servlet` I am not able to convert the `Json` into `Object` using `fromJson()` when I execute the following code.

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
Names names = gson.fromJson(s, Names.class);
```

It is throwing the following exception:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/gson/Gson
```

Any idea why that could be happening? Should I have copied the `jars` into the `WebContent/WEB-INF/lib` folder instead of a new folder called `lib`?

Comment: [See the link here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3080454/android-eclipse-error-gson-cannot-be-resolved-to-a-type) it's relevant to your error type

Comment: Did you add `gson.jar` to your build path (classpath) ?

Comment: I have added `gson-2.2.2.jar`. What is puzzling me is `Gson` is resolved in one class but not in the other class(Servlet).

Comment: What is `s` in `fromJson` call. I doubt its because of it. Check if its not NULL

Comment: It is not NULL and the error is not because of that. `s` is perfectly fine. The error is at the line `Gson gson = new Gson()`.

Comment: You should have posted complete error stack trace as well as necessary code in the first place. Read more on FAQ

Comment: @HardikMishra Thanks for the suggestion, will do it more onwards.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Okay, I figured out the answer using this post. Please read the comments in the first answer.

[I am getting "java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.gson.Gson" error even though it is defined in my classpath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4961336/i-am-getting-java-lang-classnotfoundexception-com-google-gson-gson-error-even)

I just had to place the external `jars` into my `WebContent/WEB-INF/lib` folder and `Eclipse` would take care of the `build path` itself.

Comment: Its good that you found solution but Just FYI `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError` and `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException` are different things.

Comment: I got both the type of exceptions when I executed different Dynamic Web Projects with the same code. But thanks! Will take into note.