# Save ListView Items with SavePreference Android

Tags: android, android-listview, android-notifications

I have an app that shows notification in a listview. I want these notifications to be saved so that if I open the app and see notification I can see these notifications again when I close the app and then open it. I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23899873/how-to-save-listview-in-shared-preferences-android) 
 but nothing was saved.

Another major question is how can I run this app in background? So if notification is received the app lists that notification in the listview without being opened?

My Code

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    ListView list;
    CustomListAdapter adapter;
    ArrayList<Model> modelList;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        modelList = new ArrayList<Model>();
        adapter = new CustomListAdapter(getApplicationContext(), modelList);
        list=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
        list.setAdapter(adapter);
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(onNotice, new IntentFilter("Msg"));

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);//Menu Resource, Menu
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.action_settings:
                Intent intent = new Intent(
                        "android.settings.ACTION_NOTIFICATION_LISTENER_SETTINGS");
                startActivity(intent);
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
    private BroadcastReceiver onNotice= new BroadcastReceiver() {

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            String pack = intent.getStringExtra("package");
            String title = intent.getStringExtra("title");
            String text = intent.getStringExtra("text");
            //int id = intent.getIntExtra("icon",0);

            Context remotePackageContext = null;
            if (pack.contains("fake")){

            try {
//                remotePackageContext = getApplicationContext().createPackageContext(pack, 0);
//                Drawable icon = remotePackageContext.getResources().getDrawable(id);
//                if(icon !=null) {
//                    ((ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView)).setBackground(icon);
//                }
                byte[] byteArray = intent.getByteArrayExtra("icon");
                Bitmap bmp = null;
                if (byteArray != null) {
                    bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(byteArray, 0, byteArray.length);
                }
                Model model = new Model();
                if(text.contains("") && !text.contains(" messages")) {
                    model.setName(title + ": " + text);
                    model.setImage(bmp);

                    if (modelList != null) {
                        modelList.add(model);
                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    } else {
                        modelList = new ArrayList<Model>();
                        modelList.add(model);
                        adapter = new CustomListAdapter(getApplicationContext(), modelList);
                        list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
                        list.setAdapter(adapter);
                    }
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


        }
    }
    };



    }
```

Comment: Basically you want to save modelList in SharedPrefs ?

Comment: yes this is what i want

Answer (score 1):

Make a class Cache which has the capabilities to serialize and deserialize data.

```
public class Cache {

    private static Cache CACHE;

    public static Cache get() {
        if (!SharedPreferencesHelper.isCacheAvailable()) {
            CACHE = new Cache();
            SharedPreferencesHelper.saveCache(CACHE);
        } else {
            CACHE = SharedPreferencesHelper.getCache();
        }

        return CACHE;
    }

    ArrayList<Taxonomy> cachedTaxonomies;
    public Cache() {
        cachedTaxonomies = new ArrayList<Taxonomy>();
    }
    public ArrayList<Taxonomy> getCachedTaxonomies() {
        return cachedTaxonomies;
    }
    public static String serialize(Cache cache) {
        GsonBuilder builder = new GsonBuilder();
        Gson gson = builder.enableComplexMapKeySerialization().setPrettyPrinting().create();
        return gson.toJson(cache);
    }

    public static Cache deserialize(String json) {
        Type type = new TypeToken<Cache>() {
        }.getType();
        return new Gson().fromJson(json, type);
    }

    public void update() {
        SharedPreferencesHelper.saveCache(this);
    }
}
```

Here Taxonomy is a model.
Below is the class which helps you save in SharedPrefs

```
public class SharedPreferencesHelper {

    private static final String PREFS_CACHE = "prefs_cache";


    public static SharedPreferences getSharedPreferences() {
        return SpreeApplication.getSharedPreferences();
    }

    // Cache -------------------------------------
    public static boolean isCacheAvailable() {
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences();
        String json = sharedPreferences.getString(PREFS_CACHE, "");
        if(json.equals("")) {
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }

    public static Cache getCache() {
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences();
        String json = sharedPreferences.getString(PREFS_CACHE, "");
        if(json.equals("")) {
            return null;
        } else {
            return Cache.deserialize(json);
        }
    }

    public static void saveCache(Cache cache) {
        saveString(PREFS_CACHE, Cache.serialize(cache));
    }
    // -----------------------------------------------------

    private static void saveString(String prefKey, String value) {
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences();
        SharedPreferences.Editor prefEditor = sharedPreferences.edit();
        prefEditor.putString(prefKey, value);
        prefEditor.commit();
    }

    private static void saveBoolean(String prefKey, boolean value) {
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences();
        SharedPreferences.Editor prefEditor = sharedPreferences.edit();
        prefEditor.putBoolean(prefKey, value);
        prefEditor.commit();
    }
}
```

To save write this :

```
List<Taxonomy> taxonomies = new ArrayList<Taxonomy>();
Cache cache = Cache.get();
cache.getCachedTaxonomies().clear();
cache.getCachedTaxonomies().addAll(taxonomies);
SharedPreferencesHelper.saveCache(cache);
```

this is my spreeapplication class which is a custom application class
Remember you have to mention in manifest if you create a custom application class

```
public class SpreeApplication extends Application{
    private final static String DEFAULT_PREFERENCES = "spree";
    private static SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
    private static Context applicationContext;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        applicationContext = this;
        sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(DEFAULT_PREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    }

    public static SharedPreferences getSharedPreferences() {
        return sharedPreferences;
    }

    public static SharedPreferences.Editor getSharedPreferencesEditor() {
        return sharedPreferences.edit();
    }

    public static Context getContext() {
        return applicationContext;
    }
}
```

Comment: what is "Type"?which class should i import for it?

Comment: import java.lang.reflect.Type;

Comment: and  what is SpreeApplication here return SpreeApplication.getSharedPreferences();

Comment: just edited my answer to include SpreeApplication class. Please mention in your manifest file application tag the name of your custom application class

Comment: You have to add library for them. Refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3080454/android-eclipse-error-gson-cannot-be-resolved-to-a-type
And if you are using gradle then add dependency for it http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.code.gson/gson/1.4

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93769/discussion-between-vaibhav-and-mrad-mrad).

Comment: Let me know if it helps?